# Clear table data <td> in editable table on focus using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to clear the data in a HTML td onfocus, similar to how it works in HTML input, but in an editable table that uses JQuery tabledit. Reason being that it is a CRUD table and it populates the table with data from a Db. If I want to edit one of the td, I don't want to have to delete the existing data, but rather when I click on the td, the value is set to "" and I can then just type the new data in.

```html
<td><?php echo $row['payment_company']; ?></td>
```

I have tried as below, but it doesn't set the data value to empty

```html
<td onfocus="this.value=''"><?php echo $row['payment_company']; ?></td>
```

So, this is what I am attempting to do the equivalent of:-

```html
<input type='text' id='name' value = 'Hello' onfocus = 'this.value = ""' />
```

---

**Update:**
Because it's not working in my code here the generated `HTML` from the browser dev tools:

```html
<td onclick="this.textContent='';" class="tabledit-view-mode">
  <span class="tabledit-span">onclick textContent</span>
  <input 
    class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" 
    type="text" 
    name="payment_method" 
    value="onclick textContent" 
    style="display: none;" 
    disabled=""
  >
</td>
```

Comment: The `focus` event does not fire on `td` elements. Use `click` instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I would argue that giving an element an `tabindex` will make the focus event work on said element, see the docs for `tabindex`: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#attr-tabindex When cross referencing the docs for the focus event https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-focus it's not explicitly mentioned that a focusable element will emit the focus event though.

Comment: Good point, however adding a `tabindex` for reasons other than aiding accessibility is not good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `td` has no `value` - you could use `innerHTML` or `textContent` instead. Furthermore the `focus` event fires if you give the element a `tabindex`. Alternatively you could use a `click` event.

**Working example:**

```html
<table>
  <td onfocus="this.innerHTML='';" tabindex="0">onfocus innerHTML / </td>
  <td onfocus="this.textContent='';" tabindex="0">onfocus textContent</td>
  <td onclick="this.innerHTML='';">onclick innerHTML / </td>
  <td onclick="this.textContent='';">onclick textContent / </td>
</table>
```

---

To use jQuery-Tabledit you need to select the generated child input and empty its value. You could do this inline:

```html
<td onfocus="this.querySelector('input').value = '';" tabindex="0">inline</td>
```

or with a function call:

```html
<td onfocus="emptyCell(this);" tabindex="0">function</td>
```

```js
function emptyCell(scope) {
  $(scope).find('input').val('');
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
$('#test-table').Tabledit({
    editButton: false,
    hideIdentifier: true,
    columns: {
        identifier: [0, 'id'],
        editable: [[1, 'onfocus1'], [2, 'onfocus2'], [3, 'onclick1'], [4, 'onclick2']]
    }
});

function emptyCell(scope) {
  $(scope).find('input').val('');
}
```

```css
.tabledit-remove-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-A-Live-Editable-Table-with-jQuery-Tabledit/jquery.tabledit.js"></script>

<table id="test-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>onfocus1</th>
      <th>onfocus2</th>
      <th>onclick1</th>
      <th>onclick2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1</td>
      <td onfocus="this.querySelector('input').value = '';" tabindex="0">inline</td>
      <td onfocus="emptyCell(this);" tabindex="0">function</td>
      <td onclick="this.querySelector('input').value = '';">inline</td>
      <td onclick="emptyCell(this);">function</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the 3rd option onclick clears the data in the td, but removes the ability to add new information, i.e. cannot enter new data into the cell. The onfocus options don't clear the data, although I see they do in your snippet.

Comment: UInfortunately the onclick options clear the cell, but remove the ability to create new text for updating, i.e. the cell is no longer editable.

Comment: I removed the onclick solution now. Do you have a html snippet of such a `td` that is rendered in the browser (seen in the dev tools)?

Comment: <td onfocus="this.textContent='';" tabindex="0" class="tabledit-edit-mode"><span class="tabledit-span" style="display: none;">textContent</span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="payment_method" value="textContent" style=""></td>

Comment: And the onclick is/was as follows:-  <td onclick="this.textContent='Please';" class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span">onclick textContent</span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="payment_method" value="onclick textContent" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>

Comment: Sorry, couldn't use a computer for the last hours. Thanks for the snippet. But the code needs to be formatted. For example two single quotes look like a double quote. Therefor you could wrap each code block in 3 ``` ` ``` signs. At best use the small "Edit"-Button under your question and add the code snippets directly to your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code ...

Comment: I added the code for you. It's not working because there is an input in your td. I'll check it tomorrow. Good night...

Comment: biberman - many thanks your code in the working example 2 works 100%. Unfortunately I cannot upvote due to insufficient reputation.

Comment: But you could accept the answer (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. It should help
In your html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="erase()">we</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In your script.js

```
function erase() {
  event.target.innerHTML = ""
}
```